# transforming one-hot encoded dataframe to counts

Tags: python, pandas

i had a column named industry which i one hot encoded like so:
some observations can belong with multiple industries
and there are duplicate ids, if its a duplicate i only want to count once.

```
id food    fitness   retail    grocery
1  1       0         1         1
2  1       0         0         0
3  0       1         0         0
4  1       0         0         1
4  1       0         0         1
5  1       0         1         0
6  0       1         1         0
6  0       1         1         0
```

how can i transform this one-hot encoded dataframe to where i can plot counts for each one-hot encoded category?

expected output

```
category    count
food        4
fitness     2
retail      3
grocery     2
```

Comment: id is a column or the index?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> df[~df.id.duplicated()].drop('id',1).sum().to_frame('count').rename_axis('category')

          count
category       
food          4
fitness       2
retail        3
grocery       2
```

Comment: This is great, how can i turn this into a dataframe? I tried `pd.DataFrame(df.drop('id',1).sum())`, but i want the column names to be Category and Count

Comment: @Eisen check it now. do you want "category" as index or as a column?

Comment: I just updated my question. I just realized there are some ids that appear multiple times and i would only want to count once in this case. also i did `pd.DataFrame(df.sum()).reset_index().rename(columns = {'index': 'category', 0 : 'count'})`

Comment: @Eisen check it now

Answer (score 0):

You can [`Transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) your DF like this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'food': [1,1,0,1,1,0],
   'fitness':[0,0,1,0,0,1],
   'retails': [1,0,0,0,0,1],
   'grocery': [1,0,0,1,1,0]
}) 
out = df.T.sum(axis=1)
print(out)

food       4
fitness    2
retails    2
grocery    3
dtype: int64
```

And in order to transform this Serie to a DataFrame, you can do something like this:

```
out = out.to_frame('count').rename_axis('category').reset_index()
print(out)

  catagory  count
0     food      4
1  fitness      2
2  retails      2
3  grocery      3
```

Finally, you can chain all this functions like this:

```
out = df.T.sum(axis=1).to_frame('count').rename_axis('catagory').reset_index()
```